# How to set the Color in R.color programatically

Tags: android, colors, android-resources

I have a color resource defined in colors.xml. I want to set the value of this resource programatically. I have a settings option in my app where i would display a color palette to choose a color from and i want to set that selected color in the color resource.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You **can't** edit resources programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to change resource values programatically, like `colors.xml` values. Instead of this you can save your 'settings' in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: What if i have other styles dependent on the color resource ? How would those be changed programatically ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't edit your xml files like that, instead you should use local storage,

Save your color in sharedpreferences when they select it

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("color", your_color_id);
editor.commit();
```

Then read it when you start your activity or fragment etc

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int highScore = sharedPref.getInt("color", default_value);
```

Comment: editor.putInt("color", your_color_id); // would this add a new color ?
sharedPref.getInt("color", R.id.white); // what would this return ?

Comment: it won't add to your xml if you are asking that, it'll store the value in local. You can use other types regarding to your color value.

Comment: What would sharedPref.getInt("color", R.id.white); do ? why R.id.white ?

Comment: it is a default value that you need to put, It made confusing, I edited it.

Comment: no it can't, but you can store all your colors in colors.xml, and in sharedPrefs the reference to the one you need

Comment: Any example for this ? @Ayoub

Comment: Just get RGB or Hex code of the color and store it in sharedpreferences, that's the easiest way for you.

Comment: How can i apply this to existing styles ?

Comment: First of all, you can't store it to existing xml but if your color palette, you show your predefined colors, you can store this color id.

Comment: can i set a predefined set of colors to be shown ? and from that selection can i pick a corresponding style ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48776/discussion-between-lokoko-and-nr4bt)